Ext2 Block Pointers to Block Bitmap positions
I have a homework assignment where i need to recover a ext2 file damaged in a certain way, damage being bits in bitmaps turning from 1 to 0's. Currently, i have managed to recover the inode bitmap but i am having some trouble with block bitmaps. What i am doing is that i have loaded all the block bitmaps into a uint8_t * block_bitmap, and i have allocated it with a malloc(block_size*bg_num) (I have converted block size correctly, it's not directly from a superblock) than i read the contents with
for(int j = 0; j < bg_num; j++) {
    fseek(input_fl, bgd[j].block_bitmap * block_size, SEEK_SET);
    fread(block_bitmap + j*block_size, block_size, 1, input_fl); 
}

bgd being a struct ext2_block_group_descriptor*. Algorithm in my mind works like this:
1. Go to an inode.
2. If inode's link count is 0, skip.
3. If inode's direct block pointer is 0, skip.
4. After you find a non empty inode, take the pointer to it's bitmap.
5. Convert the pointer to it's position in the block bitmap.
6. Do this for all inodes and write them to the filesysem file. 

Now, i am having trouble with the 5th step, when i try out my current code which looks like this:
for (int i = 0; i < super_block.inodes_per_group; i++) { //i = 1, k = 1
    if(inode_table[i].link_count == 0) continue;
    for(int k = 0; k < EXT2_NUM_DIRECT_BLOCKS; k++) {
        //printf("%d %d\n", i, k);
        if(inode_table[i].direct_blocks[k] == 0) continue;
        uint32_t block_num = inode_table[i].direct_blocks[k];
        uint32_t block_bg_num = block_num/super_block.blocks_per_group;
        uint32_t block_offset = block_num%super_block.blocks_per_group;
        printf("block num: %d block group num: %d block offset: %d\n", block_num, block_bg_num, block_offset);
        uint32_t bit_num = block_offset - 13; //13 is the first data block's offset
        printf("%u \n", block_bg_num*block_size + bit_num/8);
        block_bitmap[block_bg_num*block_size + bit_num/8] |= (1 << bit_num%8);
    }
}

(I know this doesn't include indirect pointers, i'll get to them after i figuere this one out)
I get this output:
.
.
.
block num: 1535 block group num: 5 block offset: 255
5150 
block num: 1536 block group num: 6 block offset: 0
536877054 

In the file they gave us, there are 256 blocks per block group, what's puzzling me is the fact that if an inode points to 15360th block, doesn't that mean that block is occupied by 6th block group's superblock copy? How would this work?
I thought about subtracting 1 from the pointer in case i have calculated something wrong, but it breaks other parts of the code. I have been lost here, if it helps, here's the superblock.
###############################
#   EXT2 SUPER BLOCK DETAILS  #
# inode_count: 256            #
# block_count: 2048           #
# reserved_block_count: 102   #
# free_block_count: 471       #
# free_inode_count: 177       #
# first_data_block: 1         #
# log_block_size: 0           #
# log_fragment_size: 0        #
# blocks_per_group: 256       #
# fragments_per_group: 256    #
# inodes_per_group: 32        #
# mount_time: 0               #
# write_time: 1687011557      #
# Sat Jun 17 17:19:17 2023    #
# mount_count: 0              #
# max_mount_count: 65535      #
# magic: 61267                #
# state: 1                    #
# errors: 1                   #
# minor_rev_level: 0          #
# last_check_time: 1687011557 #
# Sat Jun 17 17:19:17 2023    #
# check_interval: 0           #
# creator_os: 0               #
# rev_level: 1                #
# default_uid: 0              #
# default_gid: 0              #
# first_inode: 11             #
# inode_size: 256             #
# block_group_nr: 0           #
# feature_compat: 40          #
# feature_incompat: 18        #
# feature_ro_compat: 3        #
###############################

